# Error al cargar los datos de una tabla en otra - SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, stored-procedure, sql-server-2014

Tengo el siguiente stored procedure el cual utilizo para llenar la tabla Resources. Para cargar la tabla Resources obtengo el IdEntidad que traigo de un datagrid que contiene una lista de cuentas. El problema es que al cargar los datos en la tabla Resources, si selecciono 350 cuentas, me carga 350 registros sin tener en cuenta si el registro ya existe o no.
Dejo las tablas y el stored procedure:

```
Resources
-----------------------------
ResourceId(int)            
ResourceName(varchar(max))  

Carteras  
-----------------------------
IdCartera (int)  
NombreCartera (varchar(max))  
estado (varchar(max))  
IdEntidad (varchar(max))  

Entidad  
-----------------------------
IdEntidad (int)  
NombreEntidad (varchar(max))  
estado (varchar(max))  
Alias (varchar(max))  


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CargarTablaResources]
@pIdEntidad int
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

    if exists(
        select ResourceId, ResourceName from Resources
            where ResourceId = @pIdEntidad)
    Begin
        raiserror('Err -998: El registro ya existe.', 1, 10)
        return -998
    end
    Else 
        begin
            insert into Resources (ResourceID, ResourceName)
            select Carteras.cart_Id, Carteras.cart_Codigo from Carteras
                where Carteras.enti_Id = @pIdEntidad
        end
END
```

El resultado que obtengo es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo este método en la capa de Datos el cual se ejecuta por cada cuenta que tengo cargada en el datagrid para verificar cada IdEntidad, entonces me va cargando los datos sin evaluar si ya existe el registro o no:

```
public static void LlenarTablaResources(int IdEntidad)
{
  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=MiServidor;Initial Catalog=MiProyecto;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader dr;
        cmd.CommandText = "sp_CargarTablaResources"; 
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@pIdEntidad", SqlDbType.Int).Value = IdEntidad; //("@IdEntidad", SqlDbType.Int).Value = IdEntidad;

        try
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
}
```

Comment: Sería de utilidad que agregues el comando que ejecutaste, incluyendo sus parámetros

Comment: Ahi agregué el metodo que tengo en la capa datos.

Comment: Parece estar todo correto. Podes chequear que el parametro llega bien?

Comment: El parámetro llega perfecto, los datos se cargan y se repiten por cada vez que se ejecuta el stored procedure, lo que quiero es que si el registro ya existe no lo cargue

Comment: A no ser que el valor de `Carteras.cart_Id` sea el mismo `Carteras.enti_Id` me parece que tienes un problema en el `INSERT`. Me da la impresión que `@pIdEntidad` es el valor que deberías insertar en `ResourceId`.